# Pulling data from multiple CSVs

Tags: csv

I have about 10 csv files and I want to pull data from just one column in each, column named 'Name'.

There's probably thousands of entries, is there any quicker way to grab it all in handy list format or do I just have to open, copy, paste, close each one?

Comment: If you are on unix you can use all kindsa great utilities -- are you?

Comment: Maybe you should start up a virtual machine then.  Then each file is a 1 line awk program.  Or download awk for windows.

Comment: It would take about 10 minutes to write a program to do this, using any of several language.

Comment: http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/ -- csvkit does this beautifully.